# Extract digits and sum it into new cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Could you help me with create expression in Google Sheets to extract only numbers and sum it? I have cell with

```
230dr, 400dr, 450dr, 180dr, 80dr, 600dr
```

[image]

And I need to extract only digits to new cell and sum it.

Answer (score 1):

If your raw data is in A2, try this in B2:

`=SUM(SPLIT(A2,"dr,",1,0))`

**BONUS:**

If you want to process an entire column (like A2:A), you can use this formula in the second cell of another column (e.g., B2) as long as there is nothing below it:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"[^\d]"," "))&REPT(" 0",50)," ",1,1),ROWS(A2:A),50),SEQUENCE(50,1,1,0))))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=sum(split(A1,",dr"))
```